# Schema browser in SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, schema

In Toad for SQL there is an option: Schema Browser, under the Database tools. Does this option exist for Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012? If not, is there another easy option I can view and browse the tables without writing SQL?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you want to see. If you just want to see the tables that exist and any defined foreign key relationships you can use the database diagram functionality of SSMS.

Expand the database you want to explore and right click the "Database Diagrams" folder then select "New Database Diagram". After that you will be able to select which tables and views you want to see in the diagram.

If this feature hasn't been used before then you (or someone else) will need db_owner access to enable it and have it create the underlying tables that support the diagrams. Once diagrams have been enabled by a db_owner user any user can create them.

**Note:** The only users who can see a diagram are the diagram's creator and any member of the db_owner role.

More information:

- [Set Up Database Diagram Designer (Visual Database Tools)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189279%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)
- [Understand Database Diagram Ownership (Visual Database Tools)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186345%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: What would you suggest for a user who has read-only access? The best thing I can come up with is using the Object Explorer Details tab... I'd love to hear if there is something more like the Toad Schema Browser available to read-only users.

Comment: It's been a long time but Toad did have a SQL Server version of at least some of their products. If you're looking to make proper diagrams there are some products that can create them like Visio. (Could you ask the DBA to enable diagrams for your database? They're pretty low impact.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Toad SQL Server thing, as well as Visio diagrams. I'm not sure (I'm new to the SQL Server silo at my company...) but no harm in asking!

Answer (score 0):

The answer @Mike D. gave seems best, if the appropriate access has been granted. The next best option would be to use the **Object Explorer pane and Object Explorer Details tab**.

Right clicking an object in the Object Explorer pane includes:

- Select Top 1000 Rows (much like Toad's Schema Browser's Data tab)
- Script Table as > (which allows one to see the Script as a CREATE, DROP, etc.)
- Properties (which shows Permissions, Storage statistics, etc.)

The Object Explorer Details tab can show

- Fields and their definitions, sortable by name
- Indexes (definitions, columns, etc)
- Triggers

among other things.

I haven't had time to explore all of it, but this may be the best Schema Browser surrogate if lacking access to create/use Database Diagrams.